# Simplify Matrix by Averaging Multiple Cells

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matrix

I have a large 2D numpy matrix that needs to be made smaller (ex: convert from 100x100 to 10x10).

My goal is essentially: break the *nxn* matrix into smaller *mxm* matrices, average the cells in these *mxm* slices, and then construct a new (smaller) matrix out of these *mxm* slices.

I'm thinking about using something like `matrix[a::b, c::d]` to extract the smaller matrices, and then averaging those values, but this seems overly complex. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split your array into blocks with the [`view_as_blocks`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) function (in scikit-image).

For a 2D array, this returns a 4D array with the blocks ordered row-wise:

```
>>> import skimage.util as ski
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4) # 4x4 array
>>> ski.view_as_blocks(a, (2,2))
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 4,  5]],

        [[ 2,  3],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [12, 13]],

        [[10, 11],
         [14, 15]]]])
```

Taking the mean along the last two axes returns a 2D array with the mean in each block:

```
>>> ski.view_as_blocks(a, (2,2)).mean(axis=(2,3))
array([[  2.5,   4.5],
       [ 10.5,  12.5]])
```

**Note**: `view_as_blocks` returns a view of the array by modifying the strides (it also works with arrays with more than two dimensions). It is implemented purely in NumPy using `as_strided`, so if you don't have access to the scikit-image library you can [copy the code from here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py#l8).

Comment: what is the axis=(2,3) doing here?

Comment: @Teknophilia: It applies the `mean` function along both of these axes in order to calculate the mean in each individual block. In the 4D array, axis 3 points along each row of a block, axis 2 points along each column of a block

Answer (score 1):

Without `ski-learn`, you can simply reshape, and take the appropriate mean.

```
M=np.arange(10000).reshape(100,100)
M1=M.reshape(10,10,10,10)
M2=M1.mean(axis=(1,3))
```

quick check to see if I got the right axes

```
In [127]: M2[0,0]
Out[127]: 454.5

In [128]: M[:10,:10].mean()
Out[128]: 454.5

In [131]: M[-10:,-10:].mean()
Out[131]: 9544.5

In [132]: M2[-1,-1]
Out[132]: 9544.5
```

Adding `.transpose([0,2,1,3])` puts the 2 averaging dimensions at the end, as `view_as_blocks` does.

For this `(100,100)` case, the reshape approach is 2x faster than the `as_strided` approach, but both are quite fast.

However the direct strided solution isn't much slower than reshaping.

```
as_strided(M,shape=(10,10,10,10),strides=(8000,80,800,8)).mean((2,3))
as_strided(M,shape=(10,10,10,10),strides=(8000,800,80,8)).mean((1,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming in late but I'd recommend `scipy.ndimage.zoom()` as an off-the-shelf solution for this.  It does down-sizing (or upsizing) using spline interpolations of arbitrary order from 0 to 5.  Sounds like order 0 would be sufficient for you based on your question.

```
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
import numpy as np

M=np.arange(1000000).reshape(1000,1000)

shrinkby=10

Mfilt = ndi.filters.uniform_filter(input=M, size=shrinkby)
Msmall = ndi.interpolation.zoom(input=Mfilt, zoom=1./shrinkby, order=0)
```

That's all you need.  It's perhaps slightly less convenient to specify a zoom rather than a desired output size, but at least for `order=0` this method is very fast.

The output size is 10% of the input in each dimension, i.e.

```
print M.shape, Msmall.shape
```

gives `(1000, 1000) (100, 100)` and the speed you can get from

```
%timeit Mfilt = ndi.filters.uniform_filter(input=M, size=shrinkby)
%timeit Msmall = ndi.interpolation.zoom(input=Mfilt, zoom=1./shrinkby, order=0)
```

which on my machine gave `10 loops, best of 3: 20.5 ms per loop` for the `uniform_filter` call and `1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop` for the `zoom` call.